# Doctrine: Counting an entity's items with a condition

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How can I count an entity's items with a condition in Doctrine? For example, I realize that I can use:

```
$usersCount = $dm->getRepository('User')->count();
```

But that will only count all users. I would like to count only those that have type employee. I could do something like:

```
$users = $dm->getRepository('User')->findBy(array('type' => 'employee'));
$users = count($users);
```

That works but it's not optimal. Is there something like the following:?

```
$usersCount = $dm->getRepository('User')->count()->where('type', 'employee');
```

Comment: That is really ridiculous that basic Repository class can not count entities satisfying simple conditions. This feature definitely should appear in Doctrine wish list.

Comment: Why not `$users = $dm->getRepository('User')->findBy(array('type' => 'employee'))->count();` ?

Comment: @BorisK : it will populate all your User then count. Not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, you could use the [QueryBuilder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html) to setup a `COUNT` query:

*Presuming that `$dm` is your entity manager.*

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select($qb->expr()->count('u'))
   ->from('User', 'u')
   ->where('u.type = ?1')
   ->setParameter(1, 'employee');

$query = $qb->getQuery();

$usersCount = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Or you could just write it in [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

```
$query = $dm->createQuery("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM User u WHERE u.type = ?1");
$query->setParameter(1, 'employee');

$usersCount = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

The counts might need to be on the id field, rather than the object, can't recall.  If so just change the `COUNT(u)` or `->count('u')` to `COUNT(u.id)` or `->count('u.id')` or whatever your primary key field is called.

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid this, but I guess there is no other way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @luqita: Avoid what exactly - a query?  This will perform an aggregate query on your database server, which is the most efficient way to get that data generally.  Are you more concerned with avoiding typing?  You could extend the entity manager to provide a convenience method of the type you specified.

Answer (score 16):

This question is 3 years old but there is a way to keep the simplicity of the findBy() for count with criteria.

On your repository you can add this method :

```
    public function countBy(array $criteria)
    {
        $persister = $this->_em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($this->_entityName);
        return $persister->count($criteria);
    }
```

So your code will looks like this :

```
$criteria = ['type' => 'employee'];
$users = $repository->findBy($criteria, ['name' => 'ASC'], 0, 20);
$nbUsers = $repository->countBy($criteria);
```

Comment: That would be fine, if it worked. On Symfony 2.7 it raises an exception... " Attempted to call an undefined method named "count" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister""

Comment: In fact, the count() method on the EntityPersister is available since Doctrine ORM 2.3 (so it's only available since Symfony 2.8).

Upgrade your symfony to 2.8 will give you a LTS version and this method ;)

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. As to migrating to 2.8x, yes, I'd love to - sadly there's a heck of a lot of refactoring required in our system! It'll happen eventually though, 2.7 has only 12 months support left.

Comment: great answer! Thank you

Comment: I was confused by this at first and then realized it should be $repository->countBy($criteria); to match the method name. Then it works. Thanks!

Comment: awesome! this should have been built-in

Answer (score 14):

Since doctrine 2.6 you can just count the result of the provided conditions when you don't really need the data:

```
$usersCount = $dm->getRepository('User')->count(array('type' => 'employee'));
```

[Upgrade to 2.6](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#upgrade-to-26)

Answer (score 0):

Just got on an old project and also needed to get the count for a QueryBuilder when the Where conditions are already set.

I added the following function to my service to get the result :

```php
public function getTotalRecordsFromQueryBuilder(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder): int
{
    $alias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
    $clone = clone $queryBuilder;
    $clone->select(sprintf('COUNT(%s)', $alias));
    return $clone->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

I clone the QueryBuilder to not change it for the futur additions to it.

Then I call that function after adding my Where criteria

```php
$queryBuilder = $manager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('import')
            ->from('App:Import', 'import');

$dataTableService->addWhereDQLFromRequest($request, $queryBuilder, $sortColumns);
$dataTableService->addOrderDQLFromRequest($request, $queryBuilder, $sortColumns);
$totalRecords = $dataTableService->getTotalRecordsFromQueryBuilder($queryBuilder);
$dataTableService->addLimitDQLFromRequest($request, $queryBuilder);
```