# How to use strings in the where clause of createQuery in Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to query the number of entries from a database using Doctrine.

```
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM AppBundle:Product p where p.live = 1');
    $count = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

I would like to extend the where clause and use "p.supplier == adidas".

How to add this to the query?

I could use
`findBy(array("live" => 1, "supplier" => "adidas"))` but I surmise that `findBy` is much slower than the direct Mysql query. Am I right?

Comment: The difference with findBy has nothing to do with the fact this is a direct query (which is not, still DQL). A count just performs faster than a collection retrieving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103699/doctrine-counting-an-entitys-items-with-a-condition ?

Comment: When using DQL, make sure that your whole query is double quoted, and strings in query are single quoted. DQL won't works with double quoted strings in query.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should use parameters:

```php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM AppBundle:Product p WHERE p.live = :live AND p.supplier = :supplier')
    ->setParameters([
        'live' => 1,
        'supplier' => 'adidas'
    ]);
```

Comment: This is a better answer, do not hardcode or inject parameters in your query string, use parameters

Comment: Yes this is a better way, for a dynamic query to properly sanitize / escape user provided parameters and prevent sql injection, but if the parameters are static, safe, datum why add the cost of calling additional methods?

Comment: Extra cost really? We're talking nanoseconds here... It's just much cleaner to separate the query logic from the parameters, static or not.

Comment: Also don't forget that every query can be cached as every query results. Always choose an evolutive code over a hardcoded code. Speed optimization at language level is never a good sign of good software architecture. This should never be a developer's concern until the app is running, working, bug free and already making money.

Answer (score 0):

You should just have to enclose the multiple conditions inside parenthesis as below:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM AppBundle:Product p WHERE (p.live = 1 AND p.supplier = 'adidas')");
```

This should be faster than the repository `findBy()` method because you are defining a hard-coded query instead of having doctrine build the query, that being said, it is also much less flexible. This should be fine **if** the **parameters** of the query will **never need** to be **changed**.